# Template Question - delete template - delete sites?

Tags: template

I'm trying to avoid ending up with a large amount of custom templates.  In some testing I've done,  it appears that if I inactivate and remove a custom template,  sites I've created from that template are no longer available.  Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

So,  my question is:  Is there a way to manage templates -edit / delete / move -without affecting existing sites created from those templates?  It appears that if I do something with a template,  it affects sites I've created from them./ I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input,  I've updated my question,  please release from 'on hold'.

Answer (score 0):

I think if it is a site created from this template you can not inactivated and remove this template

Dorota Chmiel